# How can I use VBA coding to automatically resize images when inserted to the same width and therefore not cropping?

Tags: vba, image, ms-word

I have tried using VBA coding for MS Word but I can't seem to get it working.

I want to resize images automatically to a certain width and adjusting the height to the same ratio and therefore not cropping the image but resizing it. It should happen to every image that is inserted in any way (either drag 'n' drop or the "manual" way).
I do not want to use tables for the image insertion.

I have tried using this macro:

```
``
Sub ResizeImages()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim targetWidth As Double ' Set the desired width here

    ' Set the target width for resizing
    targetWidth = 100 ' Set the desired width in points

    ' Set the worksheet where the images are located
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your actual sheet name

    ' Loop through each shape in the worksheet
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        ' Check if the shape is an image
        If shp.Type = 13 Then ' 13 is the type for pictures
            ' Resize the image while maintaining the aspect ratio
            ResizeImage shp, targetWidth
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub

Sub ResizeImage(shp As Shape, targetWidth As Double)
    Dim originalWidth As Double
    Dim originalHeight As Double
    Dim aspectRatio As Double

    ' Get the original width and height of the image
    originalWidth = shp.Width
    originalHeight = shp.Height

    ' Calculate the aspect ratio
    aspectRatio = originalHeight / originalWidth

    ' Set the new width while maintaining the aspect ratio
    shp.Width = targetWidth
    shp.Height = targetWidth * aspectRatio
End Sub
``
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` doesn't sound like Word...

Comment: The code you posted is for Excel, not Word. Moreover, Word has two image formats - shapes and inlineshapes - and you need to use code applicable to whatever format you're using. Finally, without a registry edit or the use of a table, any linked shapes will automatically resize every time the links are refreshed.